# while trying a chat application from a tutorial I am getting an error identifier expected in Chats.java

Tags: java, android

```
public class Chats extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
private EditText msg_edittext;
private String user1 = "khushi", user2 = "khushi1";
private Random random;
public static ArrayList<ChatMessage> chatlist;
public static ChatAdapter chatAdapter;
ListView msgListView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_layout, container, false);
    random = new Random();
    ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(
            "Chats");
    msg_edittext = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
    msgListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.msgListView);
    ImageButton sendButton = (ImageButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.sendMessageButton);
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    msgListView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
    msgListView.setStackFromBottom(true);
    chatlist = new ArrayList<ChatMessage>();
    chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getActivity(), chatlist);
    msgListView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
}public void sendTextMessage(View v) {
    String message = msg_edittext.getEditableText().toString();
    if (!message.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        final ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(user1, user2,
                message, "" + random.nextInt(1000), true);
        chatMessage.setMsgID();
        chatMessage.body = message;
        chatMessage.Date = CommonMethods.getCurrentDate();
        chatMessage.Time = CommonMethods.getCurrentTime();
        msg_edittext.setText("");
        chatAdapter.add(chatMessage);
        chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sendMessageButton:
            sendTextMessage(v);
    }
}
}
```

while trying a chat application from a tutorial I am getting an error identifier expected in Chats.java

here is my code...I am getting error in these lines:

```
chatlist = new ArrayList<ChatMessage>();
```

and

```
chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getActivity(), chatlist);
```

plz help me anyone

Comment: Can you include the link to the tutorial you are following?

Comment: http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/08/building-your-own-android-chat-messenger-app-similar-to-whatsapp-using-xmpp-smack-4-1-api-from-scratch-part-1/

Comment: It the code above exactly the same as the one in your code (before @JonathanDarryl's edit) ? Because there seems to be something wrong with it. It seems that the `<`, `>` were encoded. From your previous code `ArrayList**&lt;**ChatMessage**&gt;** chatList`.

Comment: That's a good point. I was trying to make the code neater and thought that somehow when he copy pasted, some special characters got changed.